# PHP form wont submit variable session

Tags: php, session

So I got this code:

```
<?php
define("ACCESS", true);
if(!isset($_SESSION))
  session_start();

if(!isset($MYSQL)) {
  $MYSQLI = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "jo97ma98no03");
  if($MYSQLI->connect_error) {
    echo "<script>setTimeout(function() { window.location.replace(\"stängt\"); }, 1000);</script>";
  }
  else
    $MYSQL = true;
}


include "/php/ip.php";
include "/php/query.php";
include "/php/vars.php";

if($lastip === Query("bans", "value", "value", "value = '$lastip'"))
  header("Location: bannad");

$chunks = explode('.', $lastip);
$blacklist = array();
if(in_array($chunks[0], $blacklist))
  header("Location: proxy");

if(isset($_POST["login"])) {
  if(empty($_POST["login_username"]))
    $error = "Du glömde att skriva ditt användarnamn.";
  elseif(empty($_POST["login_password"]))
    $error = "Du glömde att skriva ditt lösenord.";
  else {
    $login_username = stripslashes($MYSQLI->real_escape_string($_POST["login_username"]));
    $login_password = stripslashes($MYSQLI->real_escape_string(md5($_POST["login_password"])));
    if($result = $MYSQLI->query("SELECT username,password FROM users WHERE username = '$login_username' AND password = '$login_password'")) {
      $lol = $result->num_rows;
      if($lol == 1) {
        $_SESSION["user"]["name"] = $_POST["login_username"];
        $_SESSION["user"] = true;
        header("Location: hem");
      }
      else
        $error = "Användarnamnet finns inte eller så är det fel lösenord.";
      $result->close();
    }
  }
}
?>
```

and it works, Just that, $_SESSION["user"]["name"] wont be $login_username or $_POST["login_username"], Can't find out why, Like, It works with username = '$var' AND password='...

but at the /hem page, It shows as latest user, As I used echo $userid; from vars.php, And it gave 114 which is the latest user, And not mine.

Anyone possible know why?

Comment: `if(!isset($_SESSION))
  session_start();` change it to `session_start();` only and put it on top just after `<?php`

Answer (score 0):

Changed `$_SESSION["user"]["name"]` to `$_SESSION["username"]` and it worked.

Comment: try to add `session_start();error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` just after starting `<?php` and remove what i said in above comment. and check. May be some other silent errors will there like notices or warning.